# NFT linkage between token and digital product

Tags: blockchain, nft

I understand what NFT is – it is an entry in the Blockchain, I understand what a digital product is - for example, it is a physical file with an image.

I want to create an NFT for this image. This is what I don't understand so far - where will the information between the NFT and the image be stored to prove that this particular NFT is made specifically for that particular image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) and [ERC1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) standards, there is just a **one-way link from the token to the image**. Which theoretically allows multiple NFTs representing the same image.

Each collection contract implements a function to retrieve a metadata JSON file. In case of ERC721 that's `tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)`, and in case of ERC1155 that's `uri(uint256 tokenId)`, both returning a `string` with the metadata file location. This file can be stored on a private server, a decentralized storage (e.g. IPFS), an FTP, ... simply behind any valid URI.

And according to both standards, the metadata file should contain a JSON field named `image` containing URI of the actual image file.

---

TLDR: A one-way link from the NFT to the image is in the metadata file of each NFT. There is no standardized way to link from the image back to the NFT.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it helped a lot! One more question - what about other types of digital assets (not images)... like doc or pdf file. Is it possible to do the same with them, and if so, how?

Comment: @alexanoid The standards only specify images, but some marketplaces also allow arbitrary fields such as `external_url` and `animation_url` ([OpenSea docs](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards#metadata-structure)). So I'd recommend creating the JSON metadata in accordance with both the standard (include an image - e.g. a screenshot of the document), as well as guidelines of the site where users are going to interact with the NFT (e.g. define also the `external_url` field).